# Using jQuery to Hover over one element and apply the effect in another

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="views-row">
<div>
    <h5 class="product-name">
        <a href="#">Dots</a>
    </h5>  
</div>  
<div class="views-field">       
    <div class="field-content">
        <a href="#">
            <img alt="" src="#" />
        </a>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
    $('.views-field').hover(function() {
    $('h5').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
}, function() {
    $('h5').css('text-decoration', 'none');
});
```

What the above code produces is the hover effect on all class items instead of just the item I am hovering. I tried to add

```
$(this).parent('views-row').find('h5').css('text-dec', 'under')
```

but no beans there.

As you could of guessed I am a jQuery newbie and would really appreciate a point in the right direction...

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please include a simple explanation ... ie when i hover of the DOM element with the id of xxx i want the css applied to DOM element yyy .... i actually have no idea what your expected result is !

Comment: I don't think the other answers realize that `<div class="views-row">...</div>` is repeated and that the action should occur only on each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.views-field').hover(function() {
    $('h5', $(this).closest('.views-row')).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
}, function() {
    $('h5', $(this).closest('.views-row')).css('text-decoration', 'none');
});
```

You could also use: `$(this).parents('.views-row')` to attach to that particular row but `closest` only returns one element.

Fiddled: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/Ct39b/

Comment: I don't understand either.. I clicked the check mark... any way to reverse that?

Comment: yea, working on that... was that me that downvoted though? I sure hope not because your solution was perfect.

Comment: @AdamPflantzer No you need a rep of > 125 to DV.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$(this).prev().find('h5').css('text-decoration', 'underline');`

The above should work if the div containing h5 is always above `.views-field`.

```
$('.views-field').hover(function() {
    $(this).prev().find('h5').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
}, function() {
    $(this).prev().find('h5').css('text-decoration', 'none');
});
```

Comment: Would also work better if you didnt abbreviate the css key and value you're trying to edit; Its `text-decoration` and `underline`.

Comment: It wasn;t me but some eejit is just downvoting every answer, mine included.

Comment: yea, sorry about that... i know the correct property and value there.. just trying to save a few keystrokes.. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

I would think the easiest way to do this is scope the `h5`'s to the previous element

```
$('.views-field').hover(function() {
    $('h5',$(this).prev()).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
}, function() {
    $('h5',$(this).prev()).css('text-decoration', 'none');
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle which demonstrates: http://jsfiddle.net/v39UQ/

Comment: Ha, downvoter is an eejit. This (along with other answers) solves the reqirement, and this one includes a working example. Learn when to use downvotes!

Answer (score -1):

See the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mf64r/)

Here is the code:

```
<div class="views-row">
<div>
    <h5 class="product-name">
        <a href="#">Dots</a>
    </h5>  
</div>  
<div class="views-field">       
    <div class="field-content">
        <a href="#">
            <img alt="" src="#" />
        </a>
    </div>  
</div>​

$('.views-row h5').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
    }, function() {
        $(this).css('text-decoration', 'none');
    });​
```

Just your information you can do it using pure css for that code above
see below code:

```
.views-row h5:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: -1 the hover event should be applied to the image as per the OP.

Comment: No, that's not true. This would only create a hover state if I hovered over the h5 element. I want to hover over the views-field element and have a hover state applied to h5.